# How do I use NetworkLink refreshMode in a KML/KMZ file that only contains folders of placemarks?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

I have a bunch of Placemarks organized into folders, and then compressed into a KMZ file. I use Google Maps JavaScript API to display the KMZ file as a map overlay, but about once a week the overlay disappears. I believe this is due to caching expiration. I've read up a bit on NetworkLink and refreshMode (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#Link) but I'm stumped on how to implement this for my specific situation.

When I unzip the KMZ file, the only file inside is doc.kml, which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>My Document</name>
<StyleMap> A BUNCH OF STYLES, not sure why all of these exist </StyleMap>
<Folder>
        <name>My Folder</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Folder>
            <name>My Subfolder</name>
            <Placemark>
                <description><![CDATA[<br><br><br>
    <table border="1" padding="0">
      <tr><td>cableid</td><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>spanid</td><td>1076</td></tr>]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
                <LineString>
                    <extrude>1</extrude>
                    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                    <coordinates>
                        -79.86184,40.349647,0 -79.861864,40.350147,0 -79.860741,40.350056,0 
                    </coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark>
               ... etc
            </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

It does contain multiple Documents and nested Folders. Not sure if that matters.

Do I need to upload doc.kml to the server on its own, and then create a separate KML file with a NetworkLink that references doc.kml? Won't I lose the benefits of KMZ compression? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting out with creating your own KML and displaying it in Google Maps JavaScript APi, you can refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml).

The documentation also states that publicly hosting the KML file on the internet is a requirement for all applications that load KML into a KMLLayer, so that Google's servers can find and retrieve the content to display it on the map. It is only possible to display KML files if they are hosted at a publicly accessible URL that does not require authentication to access.

If you require access to private files, fine-grained control over caches, or send the browser viewport to a geospatial data server as a query parameter, it is recommended to use the  [data layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) instead of KmlLayer. This will direct your users' browsers to directly request resources from your web server.

You can also refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) of Google Maps Platform which discusses the *performance and caching considerations* and *recommended tips* for best performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - with your prompting, I revisited the documentation and ultimately figured out what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I did not need to unzip the KMZ file into a KML file - you can create a NetworkLink that points to a KMZ file. I created a new KML file, which contains only a NetworkLink pointing to my KMZ file on the server. That file looks like this (let's call it link.kml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<NetworkLink>
  <Link>
    <href>https://example.com/myMapOverlay.kmz</href>
    <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Then I load this new KML file as the KmlLayer in my Google Maps code.

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                url: 'https://example.com/link.kml,
                preserveViewport: true,
                map: gMap
            });
```

I also explicitly set expires times on the server for KMZ and KML files, in my .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml A86400
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.google-earth.kmz A86400
</IfModule>
```

This setting caches KML and KMZ files for 1 day. You can verify it's working by navigating directly to a KML or KMZ file on your server when dev tools is open on the Network tab. In the lefthand pane, select the file to view the Response Headers. You should see **Expires:** and a date. With the configuration described above, even though the file expires daily, it continues to display as a map overlay without interruption.